# Drupal Cookie Law

Tags: drupal, session, cookies, controls

Has anyone used this yet with Drupal 7?

As far as I know Drupal uses a cookie when a user logs in. Does this module create the check around the login script or does it simply provide the functions and then it is upto the developer to add these functions around the relevant parts of the code (which sets a cookie)?

Can you simply use the following PHP code?

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['SITE_NAME_cookiecontrol']) && $_COOKIE['SITE_NAME_cookiecontrol'] == "yes")
            {
//set session here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely obvious what you're trying to do, however you may run into issues if you're just checking for that cookie.

For most cases you'll want to check if the uid key is set in the global $user object. You don't need to use isset() for this, you can just call this in an if(){}.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the Drupal Cookie Control module and from your question I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve.

The latest dev commits add a check around the user authentication to stop a log in if cookies are not yet accepted.

Other modules can now integrate in to the process with their own cookie restriction callbacks too.